# how can we create a list of custom object with each object having the data of each table using spring, hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have 3 tables with multiple columns, each table is having a POJO and with the below query how can we create a list of custom entities with each entity having the data of each table.

```
select t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3,t2.col1,t2.col2,t2.col3,t3.col1,t3.col2,t3.col3 
from t1, t2, t3 where <some condition>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can can do in this ways :suppose you have three Beans  TblA , TblB ,TblC corresponding to your three tables.when you will execute this query it will give you Object array for each row of tables, containing three object at position 0,1,2 of TblA , TblB ,TblC. That is put inside List at index 0,1...n. Now you have to traverse List and cast objects to actual Type

```
          factory=Demo.getSessionFactoryInstance();
            hiberSes=factory.openSession();
            List<Object[]> myList=(List<Object[]>)hiberSes.createQuery("from TblA a,TblB b,TblC c").list();
            for(Object ob[] : myList)
            {
                TblA a= (TblA)ob[0];
                TblB b= (TblB)ob[1];
                TblC c= (TblC)ob[2];
                System.out.println(a.getCurDate());
                System.out.println(b.getId());
                System.out.println(c.getDate());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use hibernate named query to fetch result from different Entities

```
@NamedQuery(name = "findCustomEntities", query = "select t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3,t2.col1,t2.col2,t2.col3,t3.col1,t3.col2,t3.col3 from table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3 where  t1.Id = t2.Id and t1.Id = t3.Id")
```